# UnregisterHotKey() does not work on Windows Mobile

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-mobile

After calling RegisterHotKey(), it seems to work because volume up/down dont respond when press, but when I call UnregisterHotKey() to restore default, volume up/down still not responding unless boot the device.  How can I restore them? thanks.

```
void RestoreVolumeKeys()
{
    hWndTray = FindWindow(_T("HHTaskBar"), NULL);
    if(hWndTray)
    {
        UnregisterHotKey((HWND)hWndTray, VK_TVOLUMEDOWN);
        UnregisterHotKey((HWND)hWndTray, VK_TVOLUMEUP);

    }
    else//HHTaskBar not found then try find Tray
    {     
        hWndTray = FindWindow(_T("Tray"), NULL);
        if(hWndTray)
        {
            UnregisterHotKey((HWND)hWndTray, VK_TVOLUMEDOWN);
            UnregisterHotKey((HWND)hWndTray, VK_TVOLUMEUP);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you call RegisterHotKey()

Answer (score 2):

You are not using it correctly.  The second argument is *not* the virtual key, it is the `id` that you used in the RegisterHotKey() call.

```
BOOL RegisterHotKey(HWND hWnd,
    int id,                       // <=== this one
    UINT fsModifiers,
    UINT vk
);
```

Always check the return value of winapi functions to find mistakes like this.

Comment: When I called RegisterHotKey(), I used the actual Virtual key value as an id, so for both id and vk have the same values which are VK_TVOLUMEDOWN and VK_TVOLUMEUP.